# Sharing the Seeeduino LiPo with a motor controller

Tags: arduino, power, motor, charging, lipo

I'd like to use a Seeeduino to control a small DC motor to wind/unwind a thin cable which will be lifting a small door.

Ideally, I'd like to use the same LiPo that's being used to power the Seeeduino, in the [kit bought like this](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/wireless-sensor-station-kit-1237.html).

The Seeeduino seems to have a LiPo charge controller on-board, as it has a socket to accept a LiPo and a socket to accept a Solar Panel.

I'm wondering if I take a parallel load from the LiPo, the charge circuit will see the additional load, and will be damaged, or just won't charge the LiPo. (I have no idea how the charge controller on the Seeeduino can in fact let the LiPo power the device while simultaneously allow the LiPo to charge from the solar panel!)

I can imagine a duplicate setup, where I have e.g. a "[LiPo Rider](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Lipo-Rider-p-710.html)" charging a second LiPo from a second solar panel, which is hooked up to the motor controller board, but it seems to me a bit daft to duplicate these parts, since the setup seems to work for the Seeeduino.

I suspect that unless I can take the power from the "other side" of the charge controller on the Seeeduino, where the Seeeduino itself is drawing it's power, I'll have to have a separate power supply for the motor controller.

Can I use the power from the existing LiPo to power an external circuit (motor controller), to be controlled by the Seeeduino?

Answer (score 1):

Most LiPo batteries will have plenty of capacity to operate a small DC motor in parallel with a micro controller.  I don't know of many LiPo batteries that can't handle 1C discharge, for at least intermediate time.  This would be 2A with this 2000 mAh pack.

Measure the draw of the motor in the configuration you are using.  As long as the current draw is reasonable, you should be fine.  You positive motor connection will be directly to the battery.  This is assuming the LiPo cell has discharge limit protection on the cell in a PCB.  The images with the packaging of the cell seems to suggest this.

Comment: I was more worried about the additional circuit hanging off the battery somehow affecting the charge controller on the Seeeduino, since it'd be wired in parallel to the battery, therefore it'd be wired to the charge controller too.

Comment: Please add data/info about the motor.